# Visualforce: apex:inputText - restrict input to numbers only

Tags: visualforce, inputtext

How to restrict `apex:inputText` to take number values only?

Comment: Are you interested in doing this client-side e.g. not allowing non-numbers to be entered at all or just validating at the server-side?

Comment: Ideally I would like to do it in client-side

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way you could make this work is HTML5-ifying your Visualforce page and use `<apex:input type="number" />` instead of apex:inputText.

Otherwise, you could implement some javascript validation or send it back to your controller and do the validation in Apex.

> Note: To HTML5-ify your page, the easiest way is using the page
>   element with the docType attribute `<apex:page docType="html-5.0">`.
>
> See:
>   http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/12/visualforce-html5-mobile.html

Comment: ... but be aware that e.g. IE8 and IE9 (and other browser versions) don't support this - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number.

Comment: I get below error when try to add attribute type = "Number"... 

Error: Expected input type 'text', got 'number' for String data type .

Answer (score 10):

This can be done easily with Javascript and here's an example from a project I had to do in the past.

Javascript

```
function inputLimiter(e,allow) {
            var AllowableCharacters = '';

            if (allow == 'Letters'){AllowableCharacters=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';}
            if (allow == 'Numbers'){AllowableCharacters='1234567890';}
            if (allow == 'NameCharacters'){AllowableCharacters=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-.\'';}
            if (allow == 'NameCharactersAndNumbers'){AllowableCharacters='1234567890 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-\'';}
            if (allow == 'Currency'){AllowableCharacters='1234567890.';}

            var k = document.all?parseInt(e.keyCode): parseInt(e.which);
            if (k!=13 && k!=8 && k!=0){
                if ((e.ctrlKey==false) && (e.altKey==false)) {
                return (AllowableCharacters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k))!=-1);
                } else {
                return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Standard Apex Tag using method:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.MyCustomField}" onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event,'Numbers');" />
```

Answer (score 4):

While the Javascript approach gives immediate feedback to the user (as well as the HTML-5 approach) and is hence a superior solution, there may be times when you want to do validation of `apex:inputText` on your controller.  Should you opt for that route:

- Bind the `apex:inputText` value to a controller variable of type String.
- Note that a null value as seen by the user (no data entered in field) will be seen by the VF controller variable as a String of length=0 - not a value=null (this took me the longest time to realize)
- Do your validation logic in the controller, using String methods or `try{cast to Decimal/Integer} catch{..}`.
- Issue error messages as per normal

Note that if you bind your apex:inputText value to a controller variable of type Integer or Decimal, SFDC will do the conversion for you and, if not a number, will report an error at the top of the page: `Value 'abc' cannot be converted from Text to Number`. But, null values in the box (that is, no data entered) will be converted by SFDC to your controller variable as 0, not null - which can create feedback confusion to the user.

Answer (score 4):

It bugged me too especially that apex:input does not take decimals.

Here is a solution that consumes any  other chars than numbers and the dot ' . ' (while typing).

(I found another one with jQuery attaching the 'keyup' event to a specific class, but that one did not work for me. However the idea comes from there).

```
<script>
    function decimalOnly(e){
      e.value = e.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
      if(e.value.split('.').length>2) e.value = e.value.replace(/\.+$/,"");
    };        
</script>


<apex:inputText value="{!aDecimalVariable}" onkeyup="decimalOnly(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One option of doing this, us by using [jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2.min.js&downloadBtn=) and [Digital Bush’s Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). In code that would look like this:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jMaskedInput}"/>

<apex:outputLabel for="dbl" value="Double" />
<apex:inputText id="dbl" styleClass="dbl-mask"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Attach masks to correct input fields
    $(".dbl-mask").mask("999 999 999.99");
});
</script>
```

This is explained by [Wes Nolte](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2382/wes-nolte) in one of his blog posts [here](http://th3silverlining.com/2010/01/08/masking-field-values-on-visualforce-input/).